# Connection to Cloud SQL works fin on local but not on App Engine

Tags: node.js, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I have this NodeJS API hosted on App Engine and a MySQL instance on Cloud SQL

I'm using mysql2 and dotenv packages for my connection and for environment variables access, here's how I create the connection:

```
import mysql from "mysql2";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

export const db =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? mysql.createConnection({
                host: process.env.DB_HOST,
                user: process.env.DB_USER,
                password: process.env.DB_PASS,
                database: process.env.DB_NAME,
          })
        : mysql.createConnection({
                user: process.env.DB_USER,
                password: process.env.DB_PASS,
                database: process.env.DB_NAME,
                socketPath: `/cloudsql/${process.env.DB_INSTANCE_NAME}`,
          });
```

I get to this connection creation by reading the official documentation of GCP, when I run it locally it works just fine, but when I deploy the app to App Engine I'm receiving this error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 172.17.0.1:3306
```

I think that ip and port are the defaults for the proxy connection or something like that because I'm not setting that ip on any variable

Here's how I set the environment variables on app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs14
env: standard
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
   min_idle_instances: 1
   max_idle_instances: automatic
   min_pending_latency: automatic
   max_pending_latency: automatic
env_variables:
   DB_USER: <db-user>
   DB_PASS: <db-pass>
   DB_NAME: <db-name>
   NODE_ENV: production
   DB_INSTANCE_NAME: <db-instance-name>
beta_settings:
   cloud_sql_instances: <db-instance-name>
```

I've already check that the service user has the right permissions and roles

I don't know if I'm missing some configuration or if my app.yaml need another thing

I have tried to add the ip host directly in the connection creation but I'm getting the same behavior

```
export const db =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? mysql.createConnection({
                host: process.env.DB_HOST,
                user: process.env.DB_USER,
                password: process.env.DB_PASS,
                database: process.env.DB_NAME,
          })
        : mysql.createConnection({
                                host: process.env.DB_HOST,
                user: process.env.DB_USER,
                password: process.env.DB_PASS,
                database: process.env.DB_NAME,
                socketPath: `/cloudsql/${process.env.DB_INSTANCE_NAME}`,
          });
```

I have been fighting with this issue for three days, so any help will be very appreciated for me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you have a look at my answer?